# retrieve ASIN via javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, url, bookmarklet

I would like to write a script that retrieves the ASIN from an amazon product link. The idea is to put the script into a browser bookmark so I can call the bookmark and get the asin.

I can retrieve the URL with this script:

javascript:

```
var reftext = window.location.href; var p = prompt("Bitte Text  kopieren", reftext); location.reload();
```

In the context in which I am working the asin will, as far as I understood, alwasy follow /dp/ and be at the end of the line.

So, how can I make the script return that number at the end of the line in place of the complete URL?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
javascript:(function() {
    prompt("Bitte Text kopieren", location.href.match(/\/dp\/(\w+)/)[1]);
})();
```

Comment: P.s.: Where can I find a cocumentation of what the /\/dp\/(\w+)/)[1]-expression does? It seems impossible to google. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can find a lot of information about **Regular expressions in JavaScript**. For example: [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp) and [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) and much more...